# Trying to search database for users with the user's first name

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to search database for users by using the first name which is the second column at the database but everytime i try it , it tells me user with this username is not found even tho it exists at db

```
String usernamechk = txtflightname.getText();//txtflightname is the textfield to type the username to search for
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/airline","root","");
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from flights where 'usernamechk' = ?");
            pst.setString(1,usernamechk);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next() == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "user with this username not Found");
            }
```

Comment: try replacing  txtflightname.getText()  with txtflightname.getText().toString().trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by checking if the value you pull from `txtflightname.getText();` is correct.
Try `System.out.println(usernamechk)` and check if you have spaces in your text. You can remove spaces from it like this: `usernamechk.trim()`. And the last thing, remove these ' ' from your query and formulate it like this:

`select * from flights where usernamechk = ?`